# Angular ng-repeat inside other ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a ng-repeat inside another repeat like this:

Template:

```
        <fieldset ng-repeat="fieldset in fieldsets">
            {{fieldset}}
            <div class="pair" ng-repeat="field in fields">
                {{field}}
            </div>
        </fieldset>
```

Json:

```
$scope.fieldsets =
[
    {
        fields: [
            'tada',
            'tada'
        ],

    },
"fieldset2"];
```

the `{{fieldset}}` get's outputted, like this:

```
<fieldset>
   {"fields":["tada","tada"]}
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
   fieldset2
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is simple  , change it like this:

```
<fieldset ng-repeat="fieldset in fieldsets">
    {{fieldset}}
    <div class="pair" ng-repeat="field in fieldset.fields">
         {{field}}
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Plnk: http://plnkr.co/edit/ytBGgP?p=preview